# how to make images change when clicked for more than 2 images?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm planning on overlapping 3 images on top of each other so when you click the top image I want it to change to the second image and then change to the third image when you click the second image and then it repeats. The code I'm using is only for 2 images and I was wondering how to include a third image into it. Could someone show me how to insert the third image? Let's say the image source for the third image is photo3.jpg.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 var image_tracker = 'blueandpink5';

 function change(){
 var image = document.getElementById('dollpink');
 if(image_tracker=='blueandpink5'){
 image.src='dollpink.jpg';
 image_tracker='dollpink';
 }
 else{
 image.src='blueandpink5.jpg';
 image_tracker='blueandpink5';
 }
 }

 </script>

<body>

<img src="blueandpink5.jpg" alt="Dollpink" height="600 px" width="400 px" id="dollpink" onclick="change();">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried doing and what is the response you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Have to add another if-else statement for Your third Image.

```js
else{
 image.src='photo3.jpg';
 image_tracker='photo3';
}
```

And Change the Else statement

```js
else{
 image.src='blueandpink5.jpg';
 image_tracker='blueandpink5';
 }
```

to this

```js
else if(image_tracker=='photo3'){
 image.src='blueandpink5.jpg';
 image_tracker='blueandpink5';
}
```

JSFiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/std4ecb9/

Answer (score 0):

you can store the file names in an array and call it according to the click event .

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
     var imageList = [blueandpink5,dollpink.jpg,photo3.jpg];
     var image = document.getElementById('dollpink');
     var count = 0
     image.src=imageList[count];
     function change(){
        if(imageList.length-1 ==count){
           count = 0;
          }
        else{
           count++;
          }
 image.src=imageList[count];
     }
    
     </script>
```